# Why SQL Server use Nested Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query for example:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  User.id,
  User.Name,
  Country.Country
  FROM User  
  Inner Join Country 
  ON Country.Id = User.CountryId
  where User.PlanId = 1
```

In this case SQL manager show in execution plan that use Hash-match and it is pretty fast.

But if I use where User.PlanId = 2 SQL manager use Nested loop for my query and it is very slow... Why with different search criteria it use different algorithmic? How can I fix it?

Comment: Also how many rows in the table, how many have PlanId = 1, and how many have PlanId = 2?

Comment: `Country.Id` is a primary key or at least unique? hmm.. sometimes workaround can be to use `left join` + add condition `and user.countryid is not null`..

Comment: I have planId=1 about 2500 rows and planId= about 280 rows. And Country.Id = User.CountryId has one to one relationship

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that you have a much higher number of users with a `PlanID` of 2 than with 1.

This will explain both the change in exec plan and runtime.  A `HASH MATCH` is the most versatile (and generally least efficient) join.  Basically the engine builds a table manually pairing up all the values.

A `NESTED LOOP` checks each value on the left against each value on the right, and works well when one data set is a lot larger than the other and both sides are indexed.

A `HASH MATCH` can be quick if you have a really small data set, though.  I suspect the speed difference is because of the differing size of the datasets.  You can check this pretty easily by:

```
SELECT PlanId, COUNT(*) as CT
FROM User
GROUP BY PlanID
```

...which will give you your distribution.